# Flutter: how to stop the finger in the side borders of the screen count as a touch?

Tags: flutter, touch, children, multi-touch

I have a children's app that show pictures that they need to touch to play a sound. The images are centered occupying about 85% of the width. Testing with my son of 3 years old shows that the way he holds the phone ends up creating a touch on the borders of the screen, which then make the real touch on the image to not work.
I'm using the inkwell component to get the touch event.
I think one way to solve this l would be when getting a multi touch to only count the last touch made. By I actually not sure. If there is a way to solve this still using the inkwell would be great.

To generate the different images I use a ListView/Padding ( which I managed to get some area not toucheable)/Container/Column with an ClipRRect/Image and also a Padding/Text (with the name of the image)
The app has the following interface:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with the last touch during multitouch can work, but it also requires some corner-cases to be handled.

Instead, an `Image` widget can occupy 85% of the width, and inside of this `Image` widget you can place a transparent `InkWell` widget, that will response to the touch. See a picture below for better understanding:

[image]

Here is a simple example that you can modify to adjust the gap between active and inactive areas:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final imageWidth = screenWidth * 0.85;
    final imageHeight = screenHeight * 0.85;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image InkWell Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: imageWidth,
          height: imageHeight,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'), // Replace with your image asset
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: imageWidth * 0.60,
              height: imageHeight * 0.60,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print('InkWell tapped!');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the in depth and well illustrated answer.
I did try something a bit different, which I haven't tested yet at the mobile (my son is using it now :)), but I think it might also work. I will then try out your solution, thanks again.

I wrapped my Inkwell with a padding  like this:

return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                  child: InkWell(

Comment: @Emerson using `Padding` is a great idea either! Looking forward to see your app on AppStore/Google Play, glad you already have a great tester for it ^_^

Comment: Another factor that would make it more difficult to use your approach, at least on my very short experience with Flutter, is that my "touchable" cards, are made of the image, and below there is another area (Padding) with the text. So I guess I would have to use too InkWell's? But even if I would do like that, it wouldn't give that same glow effect when pressing on each of them.

Comment: I updated the questions to add an image of the interface and the structure of the widgets.

Comment: the app is already published on the name "Speak Out Kids":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speakout.mobile
https://apps.apple.com/br/app/speak-out-kids/id6474211464

Comment: @Emerson great job! Hope I still can test it without being/having kids :D

Comment: You definitely can. It reached 6k downloads, and tomorrow it will be feature in a TV show. I'm very proud of it! You can follow in Instagram: @speakoutmobile